# Inject value from application.yaml to wsdl file

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I have .wsdl file which I want to Environmentalize. For each environment it will be same, only different will be in address location property. Exist any way how to set this value dynamically from application.yaml file?

```
<wsdl:service name="PaymentService">
    <wsdl:port name="PaymentPortV1" binding="ns:PaymentServiceSoap">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="${gpwebpay.location}"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: Nope it only works for beans. Your webservice framework should be able to provide you with automatic rewrites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [Maven Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in tandem with [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html).

### Define your Profiles in Your pom.xml

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <properties>
            <gpwebpay.location>https://default.location.com/</gpwebpay.location>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <properties>
            <gpwebpay.location>https://other.location.com/</gpwebpay.location>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

### Configure Maven Resources Plugin

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>filter-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/wsdl</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
<build>
```

#### Invoke Maven With Profile

Depending on your environment:

```bash
mvn -Pprofile1 clean install
```

or:

```bash
mvn -Profile2 clean install
```

Will end up with your desired WSDL file in `target/classes/sample.wsdl`:

```xml
<wsdl:service name="PaymentService">
    <wsdl:port name="PaymentPortV1" binding="ns:PaymentServiceSoap">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="https://other.location.com/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

In this case I specified `-Pprofile2`.

**IMPORTANT:** With Spring Framework / Spring Boot, you should use `@notation@` for your variables:

```xml
<wsdl:service name="PaymentService">
    <wsdl:port name="PaymentPortV1" binding="ns:PaymentServiceSoap">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="@gpwebpay.location@"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

### Use With Spring Profiles

If you're already using Spring Profiles in your project, I would suggest to create a profile like this:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <properties>
        <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
        <filter.filename>src/main/resources/application-test.properties</filter.filename>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Next, use the defined `filter.filename` property in the plugin:

```xml
<configuration>
    <filters>
        <filter>${filter.filename}</filter>
    </filters>
</configuration>
```

Invoke Maven:

```bash
mvn -Ptest clean install
```